# How to send text and formData in one fetch call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to send text and formData in one fetch call to a Node.js backend using multer.

I can send formData on its own with no issues, but when I try and add text, the api call stays 'pending'.

Here is my fetch call that works just with formData:

```
  const handleImage = async (e) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    formData.append("image", file);

    try {
      const upload = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_API}/uploadImage`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    }
  };
```

Here is the same fetch call with text added that does not work:

```
const handleImage = async (e) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    formData.append("image", file);

    try {
      const upload = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_API}/uploadImage`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: {formData, userId}
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    }
  };
```

It also doesn't work  if I try and user JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that you can't send a formData and json body at the same time (maybe there is a way somehow i don't know)
because multer will just take the file from formdata and the other property will be set to req.body so if you want to send userId you can try

```
const handleImage = async (e) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    formData.append("image", file);
    formData.append("userId", userId);

    try {
      const upload = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_API}/uploadImage`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    }
  };
```

Comment: Glad that helped!